# Have a navbar not reload on every page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if this is too basic a question, Angular + jQuery + HTML/CSS noob here.

I have a website (www.blog.nishantkelkar.org) that has a navbar. It has a few tabs, one of which is "About Me". I'd like the page to *not* reload when the user clicks on the "About Me" tab. I presume this is inefficient, and saving up on load-time for the navbar (which is going to remain constant at all times on my website) is a good thing?

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap open source library for styling on my webpage, and AngularJS to control actions (like tab clicks).

My effort: I have a controller that sets ng-class = "active" based on whether a tab is clicked. However, it loads the entire href for that tab (whole html) instead of just the difference in html.

Thanks and any/all help is appreciated!

Comment: would recommend showing and hiding relevant div's using JQuery, almost similar to a landing page or a one page web site, alternatively you can use ajax to load pages in a div and keep the menu static but what have you tried?

Comment: You can use [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to achieve injecting dynamic content into a container on your page, without reloading other content which is to remain static.

Comment: @person who downvoted: Can I please know why? I listed that I am a noob, listed my effort, described my problem clearly. What else is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-view` and `ng-route` will get the work done for you.

Just define your views using the `$routeProvider`.

Here is a sample code

**Main page**

```
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sample App</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

**app.js** (route config)

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module('sampleApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'home.html'
        })
        .when('/about',{
            templateUrl:'about.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo:'/'});
});
})();
```

and the **HeaderController** to highlight the active tabs

```
(function () { 

 var headerController = function ($scope, $location) 
{ 
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
};

angular.module('sampleApp').controller('HeaderController',headerController);
}());
```

**Here is the plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/HPSrLzM5BKDlmBSG1YSv?p=preview)**

Comment: Many thanks @Sachin for the example project! I understand a lot more now! =)

Comment: glad to know that. Pls up vote if my answer has helped you

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the code (preferably as text).  External links are no substitute for code in the post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I have added a plunker demo instead of the external link.Thanks

Comment: @SachinKariyattin please include the __code__ of the plunker here as well.  Plunkers are useful, but they are still no substitute for actual code in your post.  Plunkers are still external links.

Comment: Thanks @ryanyuyu for the pointer on code inclusion in answers - I see how that's useful in the case the links die.

thanks for the plunker! I've accepted your submission as the answer to my question.

Comment: Ok.  Good.  Now that the code exists on SO, even if plunker randomly stops working this answer will still have useful code.  Thanks for including the code here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, but **the better one** is to use routing.

Angular have a built-in client-side routing ([ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)), as well as a third-party [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (it's better, but more complicated for understand).

That mean you should have few separate files: mail.html and a few page.html.

in main.html you should add your header. And a `ng-view` (for ng-route) directive.
It's would work like a placeholder where you would render your pages.

And In page.html you should just add an basic page info.

It's similar to use includes in other languages.

But **important**: all client-side routing have bad deal with search engine. So, SEO for all Single-Page Applications, like an angular-based, it's a bit problematic.

So, in other words if SEO is important for you, may be you should prefer backend-based routing (at least like old-school php or whatever, to render your pages)

**Bonus** (offtop) If you just want a static-based blog (without backend) but easy for maintenance, you are able to use something like [Jekyl](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll). It's a tool, that will generate static pages from json on build-time. You can find a few alternatives of jekyl for different platforms (ruby, nodejs, etc.). In this case you would be able to host yor pages on any static hosting, [like pages.github.com](https://pages.github.com/). This is how to use jekyl with gh-pages: [link](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/).